# Alpha Vantage extended intraday data

Tags: python, pandas, alpha-vantage

I am using Alpha Vantage extended intraday data for a project and it gives you 2 years worth of data. The way it works is that you can pull month by month through the slice method. This is done to make it faster and efficient. For the purpose of my study I need to pull the whole two years and save it in a dataframe. I was wondering if there is a way to do that with a for loop method. the issue with this slice as I am allowed 1 month per request. It goes like this  the trailing 2 years of intraday data is evenly divided into 24 "slices" - year1month1, year1month2, year1month3, ..., year1month11, year1month12, year2month1, year2month2, year2month3, ..., year2month11, year2month12. Each slice is a 30-day window, with year1month1 being the most recent and year2month12 being the farthest from today. By default, slice=year1month1.

```
# replace the "demo" apikey below with your own key from https://www.alphavantage.co/support/#api-key
import csv
import requests
import pandas as pd 
symbol='tsla'
CSV_URL = f'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY_EXTENDED&symbol={symbol}&interval=1min&slice=year1month2&apikey={api_key}' 

with requests.Session() as s:
    download = s.get(CSV_URL)
    decoded_content = download.content.decode('utf-8')
    cr = csv.reader(decoded_content.splitlines(), delimiter=',')
    my_list = list(cr)   
    df=pd.DataFrame(my_list)
    print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
import csv
import requests

alpha_vantage_key='input your key here'
CSV_URL = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query'

from itertools import product
slice_list=['year'+str(year)+'month'+str(month) for year,month in list(product([1,2],list(range(1,13))))]


with requests.Session() as s:
    df_security=pd.DataFrame()
    for slice in slice_list:
        params={
        'function': 'TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY_EXTENDED',
        'symbol': 'IBM',
        'interval': '5min',
        'slice': slice,
        'apikey': alpha_vantage_key
        }
        download = s.get(CSV_URL,params=params)
        decoded_content = download.content.decode('utf-8')
        cr = csv.reader(decoded_content.splitlines(), delimiter=',')
        my_list = list(cr)
        df_sub=pd.DataFrame(my_list[1:],columns=my_list[0])
        df_security=pd.concat([df_security,df_sub])
```

What this do is just requesting the slices one at a time and combine them together in a dataframe